# Pole-placement problem

Tags: control, control-system, matlab, state-space, negative-feedback

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsB0TGRYq08) example of implementing a pole-placement with an Integral controller. 
Matrices A_star=[-5 -3 0;1 0 0;0 -1 0]
B_star=[1;0;0]
desired poles -100,-8+i*11,-8-i*11
I know the procedure manually is to compare coefficients of det{sI-(A_star-B_star*K)} and charcteristic polynomial of the poles.
I have done this and arrived at the answer of K=[111,1782 ,-18500]
Even using MATLAB place command, I got the following result, K=[111.000000000005    1782.00000000008    -18500.0000000005]

[from video](https://youtu.be/CsB0TGRYq08?t=958)The correct answer is K =

1.0e+04 *

```
0.0111    0.1782    1.8500
```

My Last coefficient is differing by a sign and I have spent a day on this. I have verified my matrices and poles, but his end result yields a different value.
Note:The video's values for K are correct as they give the stable response in simulink as compared to mine.[image: simulink diagram]

Comment: Is the entry at (3,2) in A_Star 1 instead of -1.

Comment: @SubaThomas no. You can verify from the workspace entry of the video's A_Star.

Comment: I should have looked at the video. The answer there is -18500 as expected! https://youtu.be/CsB0TGRYq08?t=972

Comment: But he did not put the minus sign for the gain after integrator, why?

Comment: The minus sign is in the summing junction before the integrator.